# Best practices for implementing a grouped table view with fixed cells in iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management, custom-controls, uitableview

I have a grouped-style `UITableView` intended to show a fixed number of sections, each of one having in turn a fixed set of cells, similarly to Settings app. Cells are custom and different between them: some of them have a textfield, another have a switch, another a button.

I know about two approaches to deal with this scenario:

1) Include the `UITableViewCell` controls and subcontrols in the same nib file where the `UITableView` is, by means of the IB. Then, set outlets for each of that cell and their contained controls (textFields, switches and buttons), and actions where needed. This way, my table view's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

   if (indexPath.section == 0) {
      switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0: {
            cell = firstCell;
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            cell = secondCell;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            cell = thirdCell;
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            cell = fourthCell;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
      }
   }

   else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0: {
            cell = fifthCell;
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            cell = sixthCell;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
      }
   }

   return cell;
}
```

2) Create a separated nib file and `UITableViewCell` subclasses for each custom cell type I have, and then load them like in the following code snippet. Here, I have synthetized properties for each cell in the view controller that manages the table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

   if (((indexPath.row == 0) && (indexPath.section == 0) && (firstCell == nil))
        || ((indexPath.row == 1) && (indexPath.section == 0) && (secondCell == nil))
        || ((indexPath.row == 0) && (indexPath.section == 1) && (fifthCell == nil))) {

        NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TypeACell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in views) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (TypeACell *)view;
            }
        }

        // Cell contained controls settings

   }

   else if (((indexPath.row == 2) && (indexPath.section == 0) && (thirdCell == nil))) {
      NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TypeBCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in views) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (TypeBCell *)view;
            }
        }

        // Cell contained controls settings
   }

   else {
      NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TypeCCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in views) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (TypeCCell *)view;
            }
        }

        // Cell contained controls settings
   }    

   return cell;
}
```

What the best approach will be? Or it could be another different way... What memory management concerns has each approach? In the first one, when setting outlets for cells and their controls from IB, cells are automatically set as `strong` properties and their controls as `weak` properties. Is that correct? If following the second approach, should I also set the cell's properties to `strong`? In both cases, should the cells be reused, even if it is a table with known and fixed cells?

I already did some research about this issue but I didn't make it clear...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go with your second approach,Create separate class for cell along with nib file. It is much easy to reuse.

Yes, You have to declare cell's properties are strong. ARC will take care memory management, you just have to set it to nil after it's scope finishes.

Here, in your case you have fixed cell but may be in future you might extend it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What about reusing the cells when `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called? Is it necessary?

Comment: Yes it is necessary. There is identifier field in nib file of cell, use same reusable cell identifier for reuse of cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: Does that reusable cell identifier be the same for all the cells of the table? Or should each different cell have its own identifier?

Comment: Cells can be reused for any table view based your UI Design

Answer (score 0):

I've personally had great success with the free [Sensible TableView](http://sensiblecocoa.com) framework when it comes to these kind of static table views.